# jQuery add and remove a class to a div by clicking on a different div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to programming (especially Javascript and jQuery), but I feel like there must be an easy fix for my problem: 
I'm working on a blog-like thing with different entries that appear one after another. On clicking an entry I want to show some content (h2, p), and change the background of only this entry. I do this by adding the class "readable", and changing the opacity of these elements.
Now, if I use:

```
$(function() {
    $(".entry").click(function() {
        $("this").toggleClass('readable');
    });
});
```

It pretty much does what I want. EXCEPT that I only want to remove "readable" on the entry-class when I click on the "seperator". Here's a fiddle with what I'm trying to accomplish (obviously it's flawed):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lkb2z06v/

I'm trying to learn this stuff, so I'm thankful for any help!

**EDIT!!! 

Sorry people, I didn't explain this correctly. The seperator is hidden initially. But when you klick ANYWHERE on an entry, the content shows up (including the seperator). Then, ONLY when you klick on the seperator, the content should dissapear again.** I hope this makes it clear. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zd1fepg/

HTML:

```
<div class="entry">
    <h1>From Arctic to Atlantic</h1>
    <h2>A cold, rainy stop on a misty island</h2>
    <h3><em>10th</em> of June, 2014 - <em>Reykjavik</em>, Iceland</h3>
     <div class="seperator">
         <img src="Design/Seperator_01.svg">
     </div>
                         <p>Random projections have recently emerged as a powerful method for dimensionality reduction. <a href="#">Theoretical</a> results indicate not much. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis magna eu ultricies laoreet? Pellentesque tempus ornare nisi; quis dictum tortor dapibus id.</p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
    <h1>From Arctic to Atlantic</h1>
    <h2>A cold, rainy stop on a misty island</h2>
    <h3><em>10th</em> of June, 2014 - <em>Reykjavik</em>, Iceland</h3>
     <div class="seperator">
         <img src="Design/Seperator_01.svg">
     </div>
                         <p>Random projections have recently emerged as a powerful method for dimensionality reduction. <a href="#">Theoretical</a> results indicate not much. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis magna eu ultricies laoreet? Pellentesque tempus ornare nisi; quis dictum tortor dapibus id.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.entry {
    background: grey;
}
.entry.readable {
    background: #c6c6c6;
}
.seperator {
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}

.entry p {
    opacity: 0;
}

.entry.readable p {
    opacity: 1;
}
.entry h2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.entry.readable h2 {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".entry").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('readable');
    });
});

$(function() {
    $(".seperator").click(function() {
        $(".entry").removeClass('readable');
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't use quotes in `$("this")`, it should just be `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the separator to always remove the class and not toggle it (which your fiddle looks like it is trying to do). Try the following:

```
$(".seperator").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".entry").removeClass('readable');
    return false;
});
```

The return false prevents the event from bubbling up and having the other `$(".entry").click` event from firing.

Comment: I tried this and it worked nicely (even in my more complex project)! Thanks Danny. I also learned that you always have to put a $(function () {}); around everything... For anybody who might have a similar question as me, here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkb2z06v/16/

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using jQuery's [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to get the closest parent match. This way, you can put `.seperator` anywhere inside `.entry` without breaking the code.

```
$(function() {
    $(".seperator").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.entry').toggleClass('readable');
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zd1fepg/).

#### After your updated question:

```
$(function() {
    $(".entry").on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('readable');
    });
    $(".seperator").on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('.entry').removeClass('readable');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zd1fepg/1/).

Comment: Is the e.preventDefault(); necessary in this case? If so, why?

Comment: You need either [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false`. Both have the same results, but I like setting the event state because I can do it independently and anywhere, and it is more readable to me, but that's subjective. In this example I used both just to be bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to toggle the class of `.entry` when `.seperator` is clicked?

You can then use:

```
$(function() {
    $(".seperator").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('readable');
    });
});
```

Since `.entry` is the parent element of `.seperator`, we use the `parent()` method to select it, and then toggle its class.

Also, see the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/Lkb2z06v/1/).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
$(function() {
    $(".seperator").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('readable');

        //or
         $(this.parent()).attr("class", "");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to do this you need to do some modification in your code i am sharing some code i think that would help you

```
   $(function() {
    $(".seperator").click(function() {
 $(".entry").removeClass('readable');       
       $(this).parent().toggleClass('readable');

    });
});
```

Demo on Fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/Lkb2z06v/9/